# Transferring files between two windows PCs programatically

Tags: tfs

I have a build server running windows 7 and an amazon test server running windows server 2012.
When I execute my build process which outputs a WAR file I then want to move this to a specific location on my test server for testing.  Currently I just drag and drop the WAR file onto my test server.  I want instead to be able to do this programatically via a powershell script.
I use TFS for my build process. Is this possible without having to install an FTP server on my test server?

Comment: Can you just network share the destination you want to move it to?

Comment: Or maybe: https://blog.ipswitch.com/use-powershell-copy-item-cmdlet-transfer-files-winrm

Comment: The two PCs are not on the same domain,  can I still copy files via shared folder?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Can you access your test sever from build server?

Comment: Hey Cece,  yes ,  that worked,  thanks,  answer accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieved by adding [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=vsts) task in your build definition. You can use this task to copy application files and other artifacts to remote machines:

[image]

If you want to use powershell script, you could refer to [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/08/31/powershell-how-to-copy-a-local-file-to-remote-machines/):

> If you are using the PowerShell 5.0, now the Copy-Item command
>   supports copying files from one machine to another through -ToSession
>   and -FromSession parameters. As the name suggests, the -ToSession
>   parameter expects a session with the destination computer where the
>   file will be copied. Check the following example:
>
> ```
> $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName PowerShellAzureMachine -Credential $cred
> Copy-Item -Path C:\temp\localfile.txt -Destination C:\localfile.txt -ToSession $session
> ```